# Why do WebDAV implementations not support GETing a folder

Tags: performance, http, webdav

RFC 2518 states:

> The semantics of GET are unchanged when applied to a collection,
>   since GET is defined as, "retrieve whatever information (in the form
>   of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI" [RFC2068].  GET when
>   applied to a collection may return the contents of an "index.html"
>   resource, a human-readable view of the contents of the collection, or 
>   something else altogether. Hence it is possible that the result of a
>   GET on a collection will bear no correlation to the membership of the 
>   collection.

As a user of owncloud I often find myself suffering from the low performance of an initial sync of a folder containing lots of small files (See owncloud bugtracker for others reporting the same issue). After some investigation I came to the conclusion that the culprit is the underlying WebDAV implementation, which yields an index.html for a collection and thus forces the client to issue a GET request for each file. Since each GET causes a significant overhead (in the order of several hundreds of ms), the whole operation never uses the available bandwidth and is perceived as agonizingly slow.

So what is the reason that widely used WebDAV implementations do not allow a client to download a whole folder at a time? The specification does not explicitly forbid it. Surely this would increase performance, so I guess there must be some technical reason to this limitation.

Comment: Nit: RFC 2518 is obsolete and has been replaced by RFC 4918 a long time ago.

Comment: WebDAV is slow because implementations are bad. Switching to a better WebDAV client will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The specification does not explicitly forbid it.

It does not forbid it, but it does not even remotely suggests that it's a something that the implementations should do. All the examples given are about retrieving a **list or index** of contents, not the contents itself.

Moreover, even if the server implementation chooses to support retrieving contents of a collection, there's no specification for format of that (how to package individual files into one download). So such implementation would be proprietary and your WebDAV client won't support it anyway.